# Auto start uTorrent in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I am running uTorrent under Ubuntu(wine). Is there any way to launch uTorrent on startup automatically? Same question for JDownloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add uTorrent to the Ubuntu startup.

Details:

> Ubuntu provides a little utility to help you accomplish the same thing, but it’s not named quite what you’d think, so you may not have found this.
>
> You’ll find the tool on the `System \ Preferences\ Sessions` menu item:
>
> Click the Add button, and type in the full path to the executable you are trying to start if it’s not in your path already. For instance, if you wanted to start uTorrent in wine , you’d put in `wine /path/to/utorrent` into the textbox. You can also browse directly to the item you want to start.

via -  [HowToGeek - Adding program to Ubuntu Startup](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-add-a-program-to-the-ubuntu-startup-list-after-login)

Comment: @subaki - Try not to provide answers with only links. Once link rot creeps in your answer becomes useless.

Comment: ok, next time I will copy paste useful contents here. Thanks for editing